# Azure function deploy error : 503 Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have a python function app created using ARM template. When i tried to deploy a function using the azure devops pipeline, I am facing the below error,

"Failed to deploy web package to App service. Service Temporary unavailable Code 503”

Comment: Can you check if your function app has started or not? Check <your_functionapp_name>.azurewebsites.net and also the kudu site <your_functionapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net is accessible.

Comment: Have you solve this problem? @Arun7even, please let me know the reply helps or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usually the **503 error** may be due to the **server** being overloaded or down for maintenance.**

As Shariful said, the first thing you should check is that if your Function started or not.

If your **Function prepared already** and you **didn't** try **too many times** for deployment *(if you do, try deploy later)*, you could consider another case that your **server protection policy** is improper.

> **For example**, if your server's access policy was tweaked to a single
> IP, limited to 10 requests per minute, and you usually click more than
> 100 connections per minute, the `503 Service Temporary unavailable`
> came up.
>
> Then you should changed the single IP access limit from 10 to more than 100, the 503 error would disappear.

Here is an [article](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/503-service-unavailable) about finding the reasons of `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`, you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting and recreating the Azure Function. Nothing else seemed to work.